# cronjob to watch for runaway processes and kill them

Tags: command-line, process, cron

I have a runaway ruby process - I know exactly how I trigger it.

Point is, it got me thinking about runaway processes (CPU usage or memory usage).

- How would one monitor runaway
  processes with cron? grep / top / ulimit?
- Can one notify the user via the
  command line if something like this
  happens?
- What alternatives are there to Monit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of writing a script yourself you could use the [verynice](http://thermal.cnde.iastate.edu/~sdh4/verynice/) utility. Its main focus is on dynamic process renicing but it also has the option to kill runaway processes and is easily configured.

Comment: Or Auto-Nice daemon -- same concept, different implementation. <http://and.sourceforge.net/>

Comment: Do you possibly know a way to write a cronjob to watch for runaway processes and kill them? I have the same problem and re-nicing them does not solve my problem. Also, the link is stale.

Answer (score 3):

The more conventional way to do this would be by imposing hard limits via `ulimit` -- it can even stop a forkbomb. As Marcel Stimberg said, verynice is a similar utility but focuses solely on nice value rather than, say, limiting memory usage which was included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that looks for all processes having more than 3h CPU time and then kills them.  The first `awk` commands filters the processes - here, those that are not owned by root.  We first send all of those processes the terminate-signal (`-TERM`) so as to ask them to exit nicely.  If they are still present after 3 seconds we kill them without interaction (`-KILL`).

```
#!/bin/tcsh

# Get a list of all processes that are not owned by root
set processes = `ps -ef --no-headers | awk '($1 != "root") {print $2}'`

# Iterate over the list of processes and set TERM signal to all of them
foreach process ($processes)
    # Get the CPU time of the current process
    set cputime = `ps -p $process --no-headers -o cputime | tail -n 1`
    # Convert the CPU time to hours
    set cputime_hours = `echo $cputime | awk -F: '{print $1+0}'`
    # If the CPU time is greater than 3 hours, kill the process
    if ($cputime_hours >= 3) then
        kill -TERM $process
    endif
end

# Give them time to exit cleanly
if (${%processes} > 1) then
    sleep 3
endif

# Kill those that are left
foreach process ($processes)
    # Get the CPU time of the current process
    set cputime = `ps -p $process --no-headers -o cputime | tail -n 1`
    # Convert the CPU time to hours
    set cputime_hours = `echo $cputime | awk -F: '{print $1+0}'`
    # If the CPU time is greater than 3 hours, kill the process
    if ($cputime_hours >= 3) then
        kill -KILL $process
    endif
end
```

Create that file as root, e.g. as `/root/kill-old-processes`.  Make it executable, e.g. by

```
chmod 750 /root/kill-old-processes
```

You can then add it to `root`'s crontab by calling (as `root`):

```
crontab -e
```

and add the following line at the end:

```
4,9,14,19,24,29,34,39,44,49,54,59  * * * * /root/kill-old-processes >> /var/log/kill-old-processes.log 2>&1
```

This particular line will run the script every five minutes at the given minutes past each hour, every day.

Short note: the shell script uses the `tcsh`, please install the shell if it isn't installed yet.